# Delayed messages not appearing in queue while using rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, pika, rabbitmq-exchange

I was trying to use this plugin and it seemed pretty simple and effective. I was able to create the exchange but when i am publishing a request, if there is a non zero x-delay value, i am unable to see the message being passed on the queue.(works fine with x-delay equals 0)

I am using pika and python; the following command was used to create the exchange:

```
channel.exchange_declare( exchange="central_exchange", exchange_type='x-delayed-message', passive=False, durable=False, auto_delete=False, internal=False, arguments=args )
```

for publishing the message:

```
channel.basic_publish(
exchange="central_exchange",
routing_key="my_queue",
body=message,
properties=pika.BasicProperties(headers={"x-delay": 5000})
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs, the plugin trying to run erlang files which were throwing errors.
It seems this plugin only supports Erlang/OTP 18.0 or later.
The standalone version of rabbitmq was bundled with erlang 17.5. had to install it using homebrew, updated erlang, now working like a charm!!

All thanks to michaelklishin (writer of plugin) for his help :)